# Inject multiple pages into jQuery Mobile with one AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am trying to use a single `AJAX` call to load multiple pages into a jQuery Mobile page and ensure that the added pages are correctly enhanced and function correctly. I am using `jQuery Mobile` version `1.4.2`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript; charset=utf8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css; charset=utf8">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<title>Sample</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $( document ).bind( "mobileinit", function(){
        $.mobile.useFastClick = true;
    }); 
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "container">
        <div data-role="page" id="initial"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
    (function() {
        function loadForm() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '../Form/form.php?platform=<?= $_GET['platform'] ?>&userid=<?= $_GET['userid'] ?>&formid=<?= $_GET['formid'] ?>',
                success: function(data) {
                    $.mobile.pageContainer.append(data).trigger('create');
                    $.mobile.loading('hide');
                    $.mobile.changePage($('#sections'));
                }
            });
        }
        $(function() {
            $.mobile.loading('show');
            loadForm();
        });
    })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So what I am trying to do in this code that I posted is initially load simple jQuery Mobile page that shows the busy indicator and then do an `AJAX` call that loads *several* additional pages, not just one. I tried making use of $.mobile.loadPage but could not get it right with that function either, and from the documentation it seems to me that this method assumes that the `AJAX` call will load a single page.

Anyway, what I have currently (and the code that I posted above) *nearly* works, but it only shows the first page loaded and when I try navigate to the other pages that should have loaded, the navigation does not work. Does anyone know how I can correct this or know of a better way of accomplishing what I am trying to do.

Comment: can you post code of one of other pages? and whether you have JS for that page?

Comment: Ok, jQM loads first `data-role=page` from each _external_ file. It won't load the rest of pages. This is to avoid url history collusion between external files.

Comment: @Omar Thanks for the comments. Hmmm. I created a sample html page with three pages defined inside and did an AJAX call to this sample html, and it loaded correctly. So there is clearly something wrong in what is being returned by my AJAX call.

Comment: @Omar Ok. Found the problem. My bad. It was indeed in my AJAX call; the HTML returned contained a surrounding form tag that I didn't notice. I removed that surrounding tag so only the pages are returned and it now works correctly. Thanks for your help, Omar. :)